# What are the minipets available from the Wintersday Event?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I see that the Gem Store has the Toy Ventari minipet for 350 gems.

Are there any other new minipets and how are they obtained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are nine new minipets for Wintersday.

- Foostivoo the Merry (baby quaggan)
- Mini Toy Ventari
- Mini Princess Doll
- Mini Griffon
- Mini Toy Soldier
- Mini Golem
- Mini Snowman
- Mini Festive Golem
- Mini Infinarium (Tixx's golem-shaped airship)

**Acquisition Method 1: Gem Store**

So far, a new mini has appeared in the gem store each day, and it appears that it's one related to the current Tixx's dungeon. So day one was the mini Ventari. Day two was the princess doll. I expect they'll continue to add one more mini per day of Tixx's travels (meaning 5 minis eventually). 350 gems each.

**Acquisition method 2: Mystic Forge**

You can craft some of the Wintersday minis in the Mystic Forge. This requires:

- A frame item (specific to the mini)
- 250 Mystical Cogs
- 250 Enchanted Stuffing
- 250 Magic Glue

The frames and cogs are account bound, glue and stuffing is not (and thus can be bought on the trading post). You receive 100 cogs, a frame, and a choice of 100 glue or stuffing for the first time you complete one of Tixx's daily dungeons *per account*.

ArenaNet has confirmed that players can only get 500 cogs per account (by running all 5 Tixx dungeons). This means you'll only be able to craft 2 of these craftable minis.

Festivoo can be crafted in the Mystic Forge by inserting any combination of 3 mini snowmen, festive golems or Infinariums, plus 50 enchanted stuffing.

**Acquisition Method 3: Mystery Wintersday Boxes**

These boxes have a chance of containing Festivoo, snowman, festive golem, or Infinarium. As far as I know, these can only be purchased at the gem store (100 gems each, or 10/800 gems). This appears to be the only way to get these minis, currently.